# JDBC built in functions and prepared statements

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a way to execute a query(containing built in DB function) using PreparedStatement?

Example:
insert into foo (location) values (pointfromtext('12.56666 13.67777',4130))
Here pointfromtext is a built in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what I've seen, the first parameter on pointfromtext function is a string, and the second a number. So, try the following:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into map_address (location) values(pointfromtext('POINT(' || ? || ' ' || ? || ')',4130))");
preparedStatement.setString(1, "12.56565665");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "12.57565757");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is String concatenation the only way out? Is there no way I can tell JDBC to escape the quotes and let it know that ? is to be substituted with a parameter?

Comment: You can also bind a single string "POINT(12.56,12.57)" into it. And maybe there is an alternative to pointfromtext, something like pointfrom_xy which can take two numbers directly.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that should work.

If not, what is your database system, and can you run the exact same command from the SQL command line?

Answer (score 1):

The question marks are not being evaluated correctly because they are between simple quotes. Remove them, and it should work,

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a PreparedStatement object is exactly to execute queries. If the query contains built in DB function is ok, and everything should work if the same query works outside the PreparedStatement.

As Thilo said, test your query form SQL command line, or with the SQL graphical tool that you usually use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put **connection.commit()** after this code?

The code should be:

```
 PreparedStatement bar = connection.prepareStatement("insert into foo (location) values (pointfromtext('? ?',4130)))");
 bar.setDouble(1, 13.67777);
 bar.setDouble(2, 13.67777); 
 bar.executeUpdate();
 connection.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to don't set doubles in the preparaedStatement? Just for testing, you should try to insert this parameters directly in the String, something like:

```
String sql = "insert into map_address (location) values(pointfromtext('POINT(" +  "12.56565665" + " " + "12.57565757" + ")',4130))"

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
```

and then try to execute the update.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've found a problem with the Postgresql JDBC driver, rather than with JDBC per se. In general what you want to achieve works with JDBC.